# Lp convergence involving powers

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a finite measure space. Suppose $\int_X\lvert f_n-f\rvert^p\,d\mu\to0$ for $p\geq1$. For $q\in(0,p]$ does it hold that $$\int_X\lvert\lvert f_n\rvert^q-\lvert f\rvert^q\rvert^{\frac{p}{q}}\,d\mu\to0\quad?$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I will assume that we work on a probability space.
 From item 6 of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2822452/collection-of-standard-facts-about-convergence-of-random-variables/2822454#2822454), we know that convergence to $0$ in $\mathbb L^1$ of a sequence of random variables $\left(X_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is equivalent to its convergence in probability combined with uniform integrability. Define 
$$
X_n:= \lvert\lvert f_n\rvert^q-\lvert f\rvert^q\rvert^{\frac{p}{q}}.
$$
By the assumption, $f_n\to f$ in probability hence by item 3 of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2822452/collection-of-standard-facts-about-convergence-of-random-variables/2822454#2822454), 
$X_n\to 0$ in probability. For uniform integrability, we bound $X_n$ using the inequality 
$$
\lvert\lvert a\rvert^q-\lvert b\rvert^q\rvert^{\frac{p}{q}}
\leqslant \lvert\lvert a\rvert^q+\lvert b\rvert^q\rvert^{\frac{p}{q}}
\leqslant 2^{p/q-1}\left(\lvert\lvert a\rvert^p+\lvert\lvert b\rvert^p\right).
$$
In this way, we are reduced to show the uniform integrability of the sequence $\left(\lvert\lvert f_n\rvert^p\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$, which is a consequence of $\int_X\lvert f_n-f\rvert^p\,d\mu\to0$.